# How to update data in array with user input values with java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a garage with three floors and three lots on each floor. I am fairly new to java, so I am really having trouble with this. I want to ask the user if they are leaving (0) or parking (1), then which floor they were on or want to be on, and which lot they were in or want to be in. Then I want to use that data and update the array to show Reserved for that spot. But what I have isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Parking {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String parkingspace[][] = new String[3][3];

        for(int floor=0; floor<parkingspace[0].length; floor++) {
            for(int lot=0; lot<parkingspace[floor].length; lot++) {
                parkingspace[floor][lot]="Empty";               
            }
        }
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);              
            while(true){
                for(int floor=0; floor<parkingspace[0].length; floor++) {
                    for(int lot=0; lot<parkingspace[floor].length; lot++) {
                        parkingspace[floor][lot]="Empty";
                        System.out.print("Floor "+floor + ":  Lot #" +lot +":  [" + parkingspace[floor][lot]+"]   ");               
                    }
                    System.out.println();   
            }
                System.out.println("Are you leaving(0) or parking(1)?");
                int input = scan.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Which floor (0, 1, 2)?");
                int floor = scan.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Which lot (0, 1, 2)?");
                int lot = scan.nextInt();

            if(input==1) {
                if(parkingspace[floor][lot].equals("Empty")) {
                    if(input==1) {
                        parkingspace[floor][lot]="Reserved";                            
                        System.out.print("Floor "+ floor + ":  Lot #" +lot +":  [" + parkingspace[floor][lot]+"]   ");
}   
            }else if(input==0){
                parkingspace[floor][lot]="Empty";               
                System.out.print("Floor "+ floor + ":  Lot #" +lot +":  [" + parkingspace[floor][lot]+"]   ");
}
        }   
    }               
}
```

Comment: In the first `for` loop in the `while`, you reset `parkingspace[floor][lot]="Empty";` which resets everything and undoes all your other changes.  I don't think you want that.

Comment: Your initial `floor<parkingspace[0].length` should be `parkingspace.length`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp No, I don't want that. But if I try to take anything out, other things don't work. Any suggestions? I have been playing around with this for five days now and it's driving me nuts. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. You need to delete the part where you reset all the parking spaces. Also, you probably don't need to print anything after the user has input their choice.

For extra credit, you need to add error checking. What if the user enters space #12345? Or "Hello"? You should handle these cases.

Here's your code, slightly modified:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    String parkingspace[][] = new String[3][3];

    // Make these variables to be consistent
    final String empty    = "EMPTY";
    final String reserved = "RSRVD";

    // Initialize
    for (int floor = 0; floor < parkingspace.length; floor++) {
        for (int lot = 0; lot < parkingspace[floor].length; lot++) {
            parkingspace[floor][lot] = empty;
        }
    }
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        // Print the parking lot
        for (int floor = 0; floor < parkingspace.length; floor++) {
            System.out.print("Floor " + floor + ": "); 
            for (int lot = 0; lot < parkingspace[floor].length; lot++) {
                System.out.print("Lot #" + lot + ":  [" + parkingspace[floor][lot] + "]   ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // Get user input
        System.out.println("Are you leaving(0) or parking(1)?");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Which floor (0, 1, 2)?");
        int floor = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Which lot (0, 1, 2)?");
        int lot = scan.nextInt();

        // Update parking lot
        if (input == 1 && parkingspace[floor][lot].equals(empty)) {
            parkingspace[floor][lot] = reserved;
        }
        else if (input == 0 && parkingspace[floor][lot].equals(reserved)) {
            parkingspace[floor][lot] = empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow I was way closer than I thought I was. I thought I needed to print the array again after everything, but that must have been why it was just adding the data before the array that was being inputted whenever I ran it. And now I can see that I didn't need to print the array again because of the while loop so it just reprints the updated array that's after the while(true). It all makes sense now. Also, I was also thinking I should add some kind of error message if they input anything other than what is specified. I will work on that now. Thank you sooooo much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a redundant `if(input == 1)` check. It could just be:

```
if (input == 1 && parkingSpace[floor][lot].equals("Empty")) {

parkingSpace[floor][lot] = "Reserved";

}
```

Also, your code works for me. I did have to add several brackets to close off methods and the class, though.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Parking {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String parkingspace[][] = new String[3][3];

    for (int floor = 0; floor < parkingspace[0].length; floor++) {
      for (int lot = 0; lot < parkingspace[floor].length; lot++) {
        parkingspace[floor][lot] = "Empty";
      }
    }
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
      for (int floor = 0; floor < parkingspace[0].length; floor++) {
        for (int lot = 0; lot < parkingspace[floor].length; lot++) {
          parkingspace[floor][lot] = "Empty";
          System.out.print(
              "Floor " + floor + ":  Lot #" + lot + ":  [" + parkingspace[floor][lot] + "]   ");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.println("Are you leaving(0) or parking(1)?");
      int input = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Which floor (0, 1, 2)?");
      int floor = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Which lot (0, 1, 2)?");
      int lot = scan.nextInt();

      if (input == 1) {
        if (parkingspace[floor][lot].equals("Empty")) {
          if (input == 1) {
            parkingspace[floor][lot] = "Reserved";
            System.out.print(
                "Floor " + floor + ":  Lot #" + lot + ":  [" + parkingspace[floor][lot] + "]   ");
          }
        } else if (input == 0) {
          parkingspace[floor][lot] = "Empty";
          System.out.print(
              "Floor " + floor + ":  Lot #" + lot + ":  [" + parkingspace[floor][lot] + "]   ");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I fixed that. I actually had the first input==1 commented out, but when I copied and pasted it to ask the question, it took out the // for some reason. Also I changed it to if (input == 1 && parkingSpace[floor][lot].equals("Empty")) but it's still not working for me. It's just adding whatever floor and lot I enter before the array. It's not actually replacing anything.